# Hybrid application HTML5 video is not playing in Kitkat version

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, android-4.4-kitkat, hybrid, videogular

The HTML5 videos are working fine in Lollipop and not on Kitkat or earlier OS. The application developed with AngularJS. Is there any way to make the video play on all the Android versions.

```
 $scope.theme = {
                                url: "http://www.videogular.com/styles/themes/default/latest/videogular.css"
                            };
 $scope.postSource = [
                                                    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value.post_url), type: "video/mp4"},
                                                    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value.post_url), type: "video/webm"},
                                                    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value.post_url), type: "video/ogg"}
                                                ];
```

html

```
  <videogular vg-theme="theme.url">
                <vg-media vg-src="postSource"
                          vg-native-controls="true">
                </vg-media>
            </videogular>
```

Comment: You should post more details on the video - codec, codec specific parameters (like profile for H.264).

Comment: we followed http://www.videogular.com/examples/simplest-videogular-player/ same and found it is not working..

Comment: Ok the video is H.264 baseline, did you check adb logs?